# is there a way to request a new tag be created?

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a new tag when I don't have the privilege to do so?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117287/how-can-i-create-a-new-tag-when-i-dont-have-the-privilege-to-do-so)

I do not have sufficient reputation on any site to create new tags, but I do on occasion find myself in need of a tag that does not exists.  Is there a feature that allows for a person with sub-1500 reputation to request a new tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ask here, but a better option would be to ask the question and flag it for moderator attention asking for the new tag to be created on the question.