# How can I create a new tag when I don't have the privilege to do so?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

It's not the first time that, in posting a question on Stack Overflow, I just can't find the tag I'm looking for.

I know I need 1,500 reputation points in order to create new tags, but is there some kind of way to overcome this rule (such as the review section if you don't have privileges to edit posts)?

Comment: What is the tag you are trying to create and on which question?  The rep required to create a tag varies by site.  It's actually 1500 on SO.

Comment: @jonsca on stackoverflow.com/questions/8654117/computer-vision-libraries, but I'd like to know if it's possible to create this tag by myself rather than having you to create it, cause I'd prefer not to post each time I face this problem.

Comment: @Matteo - You can flag your own question for moderator attention as "other" and explain exactly what you would like to do. The reputation limits are there for a reason and I don't believe they can be overridden on a user by user basis.

Comment: @Matteo: or just leave a comment asking for the tag to be created. Someone with the required rep should see it at some point and act on it if appropriate.

Comment: @Oded Thanks for indication, will try!I'm not saying that reputation limit is not correct, just wanted to know if there was a way to do it in a controlled way (such as edits)

Comment: You didn't want [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654117/computer-vision-libraries) to have the `discussion` tag, did you...? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan Is my question so general?I thought it was quite specific!I'm sorry for that, how do you think I should edit it to make it more constructive?

Comment: I'm not too active (at all) on SO, but it seems to me you're asking for a list and for opinions. (See "subjective" in [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). But maybe people like it.)

Comment: Also its title, "Computer Vision Libraries" kind of does summarize what you're inquiring about, but also kind of tells me it's not an answerable question that fits a Q&A format. (But again: maybe others feel different.)

Comment: @Arjan Thks for suggestions!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flag your question for moderator attention.

Select the other option and explain what tag you would like added and why. There is no penalty assessed for flagging your own post, unless your flag is deemed unhelpful by a moderator.

Comment: great, I had no idea that it is possible to flag for a non-negative reason

Comment: My suggestion would be to also provide an explanation of the tag and some links to further explanations.  I imagine that almost by definition, a new tag would describe something obscure or rare.

Answer (score 18):

Please **do not** fill the flag queue with tag requests. Here is a much better and quicker alternative:

Include a note at the bottom of your question, or leave a comment after posting, specifying that a tag you wanted to add did not exist yet and it should be added by someone who has the privilege to do so. If it is deemed that the tag should be created, the person who creates the tag will also edit the message out of your post. If they don't agree, they can either leave the message for someone else to judge, or remove it if they know it should not exist.

It's likely a user with sufficient privileges will run across your question before a moderator responds to your flag. Let the community help you!

Comment: I have done this in the past and it works.