# How to request the moderator for creating tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a new tag when I don't have the privilege to do so?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117287/how-can-i-create-a-new-tag-when-i-dont-have-the-privilege-to-do-so)

For creating new tag it's required 1500 reputations. I have one query on [Umbrella.dll](http://umbrella.codeplex.com/)  but there is no tag available on that.How we request the moderator to create the tag.because I don't have 1500 reputation right now.

Comment: @animuson: No that tag is not available and when I try to create it's show 1500 reputation required.

Comment: That's what the duplicate question says?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: I just check it out there is no umbrella tag on Stackoverflow.

Comment: What does that have to do with this question being a duplicate of another question that asks how to create a tag if you don't have 1500 reputation to do so?

Comment: Ask your question on SO then ping me in the comments with an @ message . I'll review your post and if all is good and it warrants a new tag then I'll create one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either post here with tag [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) or flag your own question after posting it (without the tag) choose Other as the flag reason and ask to add such tag on the question briefly explaining about it and why it's relevant to the question.