# Requesting a new tag - Jelix

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a new tag when I don't have the privilege to do so?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117287/how-can-i-create-a-new-tag-when-i-dont-have-the-privilege-to-do-so)

As I'm working with the [Jelix PHP5 Framework](http://jelix.org) and would appreciate to see this new tag [jelix](/questions/tagged/jelix) on Stack Overflow.

For the moment there are very few questions about it but it will be useful for the next person to find it, doesn't it?

So may you please create it for me?

Comment: I can find a single question that has Jelix in it, and it's not a question about Jelix. If you have a question about Jelix, just ask it and leave a comment requesting the new tag to be created.

Comment: @mat : if you speak about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034818/jelix-application-installation) it is a jelix question even if related to the filesystem

Comment: @FoxMaSk: I think Mat meant [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504355/one-code-many-websites)...which should be burned *hard*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags don't exist in isolation. They need to be attached to questions to exist.

If you have the required reputation just add the tag to any questions you ask.

If you don't have the reputation then either leave a comment on the question or ask in here for someone with the required reputation to add the tag.

So are there any existing questions that would benefit from this tag being added to them?