# Request for a new tag: kinect-toolbox

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, tag-creation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a new tag when I don't have the privilege to do so?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117287/how-can-i-create-a-new-tag-when-i-dont-have-the-privilege-to-do-so)
>   [Can we please have the [foo] tag on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/can-we-please-have-the-foo-tag-on-so)

[Kinect.Toolbox](http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/) is now one of the most famous and useful libraries for gesture recognition and NUI for kinect SDK. I don't have enough privilages to create a new tag in stackoverflow. I think it will be very useful to add this tag if there is someone who has enough privilages to do so.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705194/kinect-toolbox-and-magnetic-controlls-when-navigating-between-pages) is the question I posted which is related to Kinect.Toolbox but I couldn't find the tag in the existing ones. ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the best solution, If you do not have enough [privileges to create a new tag](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags), Just flag the question you want to a new tag and tell the moderator to add a new tag. Like this one:

[image]

[Look at this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117287/187824) which is related to this answer.

Comment: Please **don't** fill the flag queue with tag requests. Instead [append an additional message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134893) to the question and let the community create it for you.

Comment: @animuson Actually your suggestion is more preferable and faster. Any 1500+ user who read the question will surely create a tag after reading a comment or P.S.

Answer (score 3):

[Done](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12705194/2).

Now go [provide a good wiki summary](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/84570).

Comment: @Mahsa, well you can do it, this is the link [help us create](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kinect.toolbox)