# New tag request for Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags

I'd like to request a new tag of [google-cloud-messaging](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging), with a possible synonym of [gcm](/questions/tagged/gcm) unless that is likely to clash with something else, or is deemed too short.  [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) replaces the c2dm service, which was [officially depreciated on 26th June 2012](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/).

I was originally going to request these as synonyms of [android-c2dm](/questions/tagged/android-c2dm), but the service is only being deprecated and nobody is being forced to move (yet), a new tag seems the better option.

Comment: See [is there a way to request a new tag be created?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115047)

Comment: Yes, I had seen that one, but I thought I'd also seen one saying you could suggest them here.  Must have been a merge/synonym request, or a brainfart on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flag questions that you feel could use that tag for moderator attention (ask for the additional tag to be added), or retag the questions yourself ([requires >= 1500 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags)) and the tag will be created automatically.

In other words, tags are not created on their own; they need at least one question to be attached to.

Comment: I thought you needed 1500 rep for the [create new tags privilege on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags).  Does retagging bypass this?

Comment: @Chilledrat: No, sorry, I had MSO and SO mixed up; it is easier here. I've updated the privilege rep requirement and link to reflect.

Comment: Please don't flag for edits, anyone can propose a suggested edit, there is no need to involve moderators in this.

Comment: @MadScientist: But you cannot *create new tags* with a proposed edit when your rep is below 1500.